# I can't install app APK in Android 10 devices & below. Using Firebase Firestore as database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, apk

I can't install my app from the APK.

When trying to install app in Android 10 & below devices, this error pops up:

> There was a problem while parsing the package

In Android 11 and higher version devices, it is okay.

I am not sure why this happens, hope I can get an answer here.

My db is Firebase Firestore.

implement this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.7'
```

Plugin:

```
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
```

Comment: There is no code that downloads a file to storage. Also ther is no code that tries to install an apk from storage. If you download a file it will be stored. It will not automatically be installed so a parse error is not possible while downloading and storing.

Comment: do you have any solving method? or any link i can refer to? Sorry for the disturb and i very appreciate it.

Comment: Please comment on my comments first.

Comment: wht u means by comment on your comment? Sorry newbie here